# Why can't I delete data with Vuejs

Tags: firebase, vue.js, vue-resource

Although it says status:ok in the console, the data in the firebase data is not deleted, where am I doing wrong?

`

```
deleteUser(userKey){
      this.$resource("users" + userKey + ".json").delete()
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response)
      })
     }
```

`

[image: Console ss]

[image: Firebase ss]

Comment: Missing a `/` to access users.  `this.$resource(“users/“ + …`